# How to properly use Spring AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.setEntityManagerInitializer method?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, event-listener, entitymanager

I'm using `ContextRefreshedEvent` on `@SpringBootApplication` class.
It seems to work, but is it recommended approach?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void customizeEntityManagerFactory() {
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setEntityManagerInitializer(entityManager -> {
            Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            session.enableFilter("deletedProductFilter").setParameter("isDeleted", false);
        });
    }
}
```